# Vim case-insensitive filename completion

Tags: vim, autocomplete, case-sensitive, tab-completion

I recently noticed how to configure bash to do case-insensitive filename completion (in /etc/inputrc, add: set completion-ignore-case on), now how do I get this in vim?

Comment: Huh I thought that was default and was mildly bothered by it; both gVim on Windows and MacVim do case-insensitive filename completion.

Comment: @dash-tom-bang both in windows and in mac case does not matter (though, as I know, you can alter it in mac). On linux it does.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Try

> :set wildignorecase

I believe it is a pretty new feature, I have it working in the latest vim build(7.3.107)

see [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/vim_dev@googlegroups.com/msg12024.html).

Comment: Perfect. For people who want to put this in their vimrc, you might want to test for the feature first. Copy-and-pasteable version: https://gist.github.com/3372724

Comment: This works only for file name completions on the command line (`:`). Doesn't work with file name completions in insert mode (`^X^F`), which is still case-sensitive.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it's not supported yet.  It appears in vim's todo list `:help todo` search for `CASE_INSENSITIVE_FILENAME` (with priority "next release"):

> 8   Some file systems are case-sensitive, some are not.  Turn
>       CASE_INSENSITIVE_FILENAME into an option, at least for completion.

Anyway, if you don't care to rebuild vim from source then you can try this patch:
http://osdir.com/ml/vim_dev/2009-09/msg00006.html

(Haven't tried it, so I cannot guarantee that it will solve your problem. Sorry)